# Multiple content: attr() values

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

I'm trying to display 2 things in my elements; the `class` name and an own created `data-size` variable. Seperated with one white space.

I could get this working by doing this:

```
.element:before {
   content: attr(class);
}

.element:after {
   content: attr(data-size);
}
```

But it doesnt seem like a the right way to do it. I have also tried to do this:

```
.element:before {
   content: attr(class data-size);
}
```

But that didnt work aswell.

**Input**

*HTML*

```
<div class="element" data-size="20"></div>
```

*CSS*

```
.element:before {
    content: attr(class data-size);
}
```

**Wanted output**

element 20

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vD4E3/)

Comment: try `attr(class)" "attr(data-size)`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To concatenate two or more string values in CSS, [separate them with whitespace](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vD4E3/6):

```
.element:before {
    content: attr(class) ' ' attr(data-size);
}
```

Note that the whitespace between the `attr()` functions and the quotes is not the same as the whitespace *within* the quotes. The latter is an actual string containing a space character, which will separate the two attribute values in the output. The whitespace between the three parts is the operator that joins them together.

Comment: Thank you, accepting your answer when i can. Can i do this as many times as i want and can i put other things in here aswell?

Comment: @Bas: Yes, you can do this with as many strings as you want. You can also place any other string you want as long as you put it in quotes, for example `content: attr(data-foo) ' abc';`

Comment: ah okay, didnt know. Is it possible to insert a new line aswell?

Comment: @Bas: Yes, to insert a newline use `'\A'`. You will need to add `white-space: pre` or `pre-wrap` to your rule in order to get it to actually render a line break. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vD4E3/9

Comment: This didnt work for some reason: `content: attr(class) '\A' attr(data-size);`

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention the bit about `white-space`. I've added a demo.

Comment: It should also be mentioned **strongly** that the properly is not meant to display **actual** content. It's supposed to be used for styling in conjunction with pseudo-elements - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content