# How can I use an element's data-etc attribute value for CSS property values?

Tags: html, css

I want to use multiple data attribute in single css. So is that possible.?

I had created css given blow, i want to use `data-letters` and `data-color` both in css but it is not working.

data-color will placed at background and data-letters will placed at content in css

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

[data-letters]:before {
    content: attr(data-letters);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 32px;
    width: 85px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #95A73B;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 1em;
    color: white;
    margin-top:  20px;
}
```

```html
<p data-letters="PB" data-color="#c0227a"></p>
```

Comment: What happens when you change `css[data-letters]` as `css[data-letters]="PB"` ?

Comment: didn't tried that. Can you please give me an example.

Comment: Would it be possible for put this in a fiddle / pen and to make the debugging easier?

Comment: Js filddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q4uez8x9/

Comment: There is little browser support for using `attr()` for anything other than the `content` property of pseudo elements right now, I think. If you want to set colors etc. dynamically, then you should look into CSS variables (can be set via inline styles.)

Answer (score 12):

### TL;DR:

**You can't**. (As of September 2023) [no browser supports](https://caniuse.com/css3-attr) using `attr()` for anything *except* only the `content:` property on `::before` and `::after` boxes:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr
- https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_attr_type-or-unit

### Backstory:

- CSS's `attr()` function *theoretically* allows you to use *any* element attribute from the DOM for *any* CSS property value.

  - However, as of early 2022 you can only use `attr()` with CSS's `content:` property, which only applies to the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.
  - But [you *can* concatenate multiple attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427945/multiple-content-attr-values) within `content:` though, e.g.:

```css
  body { font-family: sans-serif; }

  [data-letters]:before {
    content: attr(data-letters) ' ' attr(data-color);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #95A73B;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
  <p data-letters="PB" data-color="#c0227a"></p>
```

...but this isn't what you're looking for.

---

- Note that conceptually the `attr()` function in CSS returns an arbitrary text **string** value, rather than a "*typed*" value.

  - So a string "`#aabbcc`" is not the same thing as a CSS-color-*typed* value `#aabbcc`, which is one of the reasons why we can't do `color: attr(data-color);`.
  - Note that even if `color: attr(data-color);` was supported by browsers, it would be the equivalent of doing `color: "#aabbcc"` instead of `color: #aabbcc`, which is invalid, so it wouldn't work anyway *even if it was supported*.

    - Hence the need for *typed* values.
    - (I note that we *can* reuse arbitrary custom-properties with real properties regardless of their type, and custom-properties tend to *feel* like string values (but they aren't) and so it feels inconsistent - but let's just pretend *this isn't a thing* for now)
  - ...I do agree it is surprising that support for this would be straightforward to implement, and has been an open issue [for over 14 years now](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=435426).
- I *speculate* the reason why browsers don't (yet) support `attr()` for other properties is because you could just set an inline `style=""` attribute on the element to get the same end-result (well, except for `::before` and `::after`, of course, as those boxes don't map 1:1 to a DOM element).
- If you want to track implementation progress:

  - [Chrome / Chromium / Blink / Edge, since 2013](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246571).
  - [Firefox / Gecko, since 2008](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=435426).
  - [Safari / Apple WebKit, since 2009](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26609)

### Alternatives

As mentioned, you can use an inline `style=""` attribute to set properties on a per-element basis; so if you use the inline style to set custom-properties then those custom-properties can be used by any `::before` and `::after` boxes' style rules without needing to set explicit style properties on their parent, like so:

```css
  body { font-family: sans-serif; }

  [data-letters]:before {
    content: attr(data-letters);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--my-color);
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
  <p style="--my-color: #c0227a;" data-letters="PB"></p>
```

...though I agree this is inelegant and necessarily means duplicating values in both `data-` attributes and inside the `style=""` attribute (assuming you wanted to keep the `data-` attributes too).

Comment: i had used alternative solution and it is working fine. Thanks for help